# How to show array from parse.com in a textview inside of a uitableviewcell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

Trying to display an array pulled from parse.com in a textview inside of a uitableviewcell. Everything else is showing but I can't seem to get a array to display in a textview. This is the code I have. I'm getting fatal error: Array index out of range for myCell2.feedbacktextview.text = feedback![indexPath.row]

```
var feedback: [String]?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
     query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects  {
                 if object.objectForKey("Comments") != nil {

                   self.feedback = object.objectForKey("Comments") as! [String]

                    }
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
 }}}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let myCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedcell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourAdviseControllerCell
      myCell2.feedbacktextview.text = feedback![indexPath.row]
      return myCell2
}
```

edit:
    self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile1"] as! PFFile)

```
                    self.imageFiles2.append(object["imageFile2"] as! PFFile)

                    self.usernames.append(object["message"] as! String)

                    self.usernames2.append(object["declaration"] as! String)

                    self.usernames3.append(object["whichbutton"] as! String)
```

Comment: Hi I have a question because I'm stuck in something similar to this. You are trying to get users to comment on a post right? If so, when you press the reply button or something, even though it's not showing up on the app, is it updating on the database?

Comment: no in my app its messages, sending messages updates in the database, but i cant get it to show for the receiver of the message when looking at his post.

Comment: Ohhh, I see, well I guess that the coding part should be similar in the way you are fetching the data from the database, just being displayed differently. But yeah I'm having trouble too.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you did is intentionally correct but a fair share of small mistakes are left to correct. The takeaway would be never use forced unwrapping when possible.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let myCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedcell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourAdviseControllerCell
  //This below line fetches the value from feedback if it has else gives ""
  myCell2.feedbacktextview.text = feedback?[indexPath.row] ?? ""
  return myCell2
}
```

That would solve the problem for now but i see if this code gets called when then you might be returning some valid values from the numberOfRowsInCells method without respect to the feedback value. Ideally i would do something like this:

```
var feedback:[String]?

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return feedback?.count ??  0
}
```

Even then there is a slight problem i guess. Don't call tableView.reloadData() from a block which is executing in a separate thread or queue. Do all the work in main queue.

```
  if object.objectForKey("Comments") != nil {

               self.feedback = object.objectForKey("Comments") as! [String]

                }
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
   }
```

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: wait where would i put it then because i am getting a longrunning parse operation is being executed on main thread

Comment: wrap your self.tableView.reloadData() in a main queue which is this code:  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })     at it is

Comment: im grapping other stuff from parse too i edited my main post to show, how would i put the self.tableView.reloadData(), do i do it for each individual one?

Comment: Replace [self.tableView.reloadData()] with this [dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })]  once and for all. No worries

Comment: not sure if the code u provided above solves my problem but feedback is an array that I was to put into a textview, so if it is ["a","b","c"] i want the table view to show a b c on seperate lines